# Join in laravel indexQuery and filter apply

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-nova

I have custom indexQuery

```php
$resourceTable = 'soft';
$user = Auth::user();

$orderBy = $request->get('orderBy');
$dir = $request->get('orderByDirection');

$query->select(DB::raw("{$resourceTable}.*"));

if (!$user->isGlobalAdmin) {
    $roles = json_decode($user->getRoleNames());
    $rolesArray = [];
    foreach ($roles as $roleName) {
        $role = json_decode(Role::findByName($roleName));
        $rolesArray[] = $role->id;
    }

    $query->join('model_has_roles', 'model_id', '=', "{$resourceTable}.id")
        ->where('model_type', '=', 'App\Models\Soft')
        ->whereIn('role_id', $rolesArray);
}
```

When I load index page of resource sql is

```sql
select soft.* from `soft` 
inner join `model_has_roles` on `model_id` = `soft`.`id` 
where `model_type` = 'App\\Models\\Soft' and `role_id` in (2, 3)
```

And I have filter with roles.

code for apply is

```php
$roles = $value;
$rolesArray = [];
foreach ($roles as $roleName) {
    $role = json_decode(Role::findByName($roleName));
    $rolesArray[] = $role->id;
}

return $query->whereIn('role_id', $rolesArray);
```

When I set one in filter I get sql

```sql
select soft.* from `soft` 
inner join `model_has_roles` on `model_id` = `soft`.`id` 
where `role_id` in (3) and `model_type` = App\\Models\\Soft and `role_id` in (2, 3)
```

2 times role_id IN, how to correct it to only one time?

Answer (score 0):

By making sure every role_id is in the first or second array `$rolesArray` when querying: `$query->whereIn('role_id', $rolesArray);`
And removing one of the two query statements

Comment: How I can be sure? First query its for index recourse, second for filter